# How to get the value of <PasswordBox in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, passwordbox

I am pretty new to Silverlight and just now realised that there is a passwordbox control in Silverlight 2. But there are not much articles about how to get the value from this control. Is it similar to TextBox control. Can I use the .text proprty to get the value (but intellisense does not show this property)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect you want the [Password property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: Damn! How did I miss that property! and Thanks .. that was quick! :)

Comment: Never underestimate Jon Skeet. :)

Comment: I underestimated him one time, then my RAID-1 set imploded.